# Why is the type annotation on global variables displaying as Any?

Tags: python-3.x, annotations

I have the following code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Body
from jupyter_client import KernelManager
from jupyter_client.blocking.client import BlockingKernelClient

app = FastAPI()
km = KernelManager(kernel_name="python3")
client: BlockingKernelClient = km.blocking_client()
```

But, for some reason, when I mouse over `client` in VsCode, it is marked as `Any`. Why is this happening?